# Meteor update without user

Tags: meteor

I want to add anonymous voting to my website, no login required. I'm trying to do an update on the client with Collection.update, but get Access Denied or update failed: Internal server error. What's the correct way to allow anyone to update a collection? Cheers!

Comment: What does your update look like? You're not allowed to do just any update from the client (by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is to use anonymous user, and there's a neat package for that https://github.com/artwells/meteor-accounts-guest

Or, as suggested in the comments, use allow/deny rules.

Comment: No! The solution is to use allow/deny rules.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you need to pass user to allow/deny rules, as in update:  function(userId, doc).

Comment: No you don't. userId and doc are *optional* parameters of that function. So you can basically `return true;` to allow every insert.